# Compare two time in vba 30/12/1899 error

Tags: excel, vba

in one long code I've one step to compare two times (var cell and var h), the both  value are the same.
below that I can saw on immediate view:

```
Debug.Print Format(cell, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); " "; Format(h, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
30/12/1899 02:30:00 30/12/1899 02:30:00
if h=cell then debug.Print "yes" else debug.Print "no"
no
debug.print cell-h
 3,46944695195361E-16
```

Ho I can compare the two times and retreive the correct result (true in my example)
thnk Fabrizio

Comment: Date value  starts from  year 1900. So 1899 year is  nothing in computer time.

Comment: Show us how you're assigning to the variables `cell` and `h`. That'll help us understand your situation a bit more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

A common way in **any Langage** :

To compare 2 dates time convert each date in string using [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format :

For VBA :

```
Format(cell, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") // for a second precision
Format(cell, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm") // for a minute precision
Format(cell, "yyyy-MM-dd") // for a day precision
Format(cell, "yyyy") // for a year precision etc...
```

After you can simply compare the strings

*Note : the best practice is to using specific comparator function for each Langage*